# How to tell if a process is out of control with Process Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, debug

Besides seeing constantly high CPU usage and growing memory usage in Task Manager, and without relying on a determination based on actual interaction with the program (e.g., sluggish interface), is there another way to determine if a process is malfunctioning (and/or out of control) with Process Explorer?

For example, I'm looking at the Threads box of a particular process in Process Explorer. I see about 20-30 "stagnant" threads of `MSVCR100.dll!endthreadex`. Is there a way to roughly estimate if a process is malfunctioning by looking at the Threads and Call Stacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to roughly estimate if a process is malfunctioning by looking at the Threads and Call Stacks?

It really depends on the process - the more familiar you are with the program and its "normal" resource allocations, the more easily you'll be able to identify when it is malfunctioning.  I say it depends on the process because what is "normal" for one application might be horribly wrong for another.

In your example, the '20-30 stagnant threads' might be indicative of a problem, or not - it depends on whether this is intentional or not.

Something that should also come into play is whether the application's performance / resource usage is up to your standards as a user.  If you're looking at the process information and see these stagnant threads often, and it's impacting you as a user, you may decide to remove / replace the app with a better performing one.

**Usually, we tend to rely on the more memory usage and cpu time as indications something is wrong, as these resources more directly impact performance of other applications.**

Comment: Thanks. The main reason I ask about it is because sometimes I wonder (worry) if a program is actually "malfunctioning", but it's not apparent to me because my machine's resources can handle it. Now one might say, "Well, in that case, that's not really a problem." It stems from a slight worry of a program pageing things to disk. I have a bit of OCD where I wonder if my SSD is getting "shredded". (I'm aware that an SSD getting written to "death" is mostly a non-issue, and wouldn't happen until years after the SSD has served its purpose)

Comment: So anyway, I guess it's a long way of saying that it's mostly a matter of wanting to solve problems and make sure things are functioning correctly, as well as a pinch of raging OCD :)